# Is there a clever way to group a bunch of files together besides using a folder (for Windows desktop background images)?

Tags: windows, desktop, desktop-customization, photos, background

I have many photographs, and I want to pick about 1000 of them to use as Windows desktop backgrounds (aka wallpapers).

The easiest thing to do is copy the ones I want into their own folder, and then tell Windows to use that folder for desktop backgrounds.

But that involves wasting storage and also making sure I don't accidentally move any files instead of just copying them (and then having to remember in a few years that I copied them, and didn't move them).

Is there a more clever way to approach this?

I tried creating a folder filled with shortcuts to a few of the images I wanted, but Windows did not recognize the shortcuts for using their corresponding images as desktop backgrounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create [hard links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) using the [mklink](https://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html) command to link the specific image files you want to display in the same folder rather than shortcuts or [symbolic] soft links (e.g. `lnk` files).

Once you create the hard link, the actual file content consuming the disk space will not be purged unless both the link and the original file are deleted. If one or the other are deleted, the file stays until both are deleted.

Essentially this creates another file that merely points to the same location on the disk the actual content resides so two files will share that same pointer essentially and not be duplicated.

---

### Batch [cmd] Commands

```
cd /d "D:\Images\WallPaper"
mklink /H "Cool.jpg" "D:\Photos\2019\Jan\Cool.jpg"
mklink /H "Lightning.jpg" "D:\Photos\2009\Dec\Lightning.jpg"
```

**Important:** Be sure to `cd /d` to the folder which you will point the wallpaper slideshow to view, and you'll need to be sure the ***hard links and files are located on the same drive partition***.

**Note:** There are two parameter values to specify after the `mklink /H`. The first value is the name of the file\link only, and the second is the full path to the orginal file you want to link it to.

---

### Powershell Commands

You can also create hard links with PowerShell so below are a couple examples of those commands.

```
New-Item -ItemType HardLink -Path "D:\WallPaper\cool.jpg" -Target "D:\Photos\2019\Jan\Cool.jpg"
New-Item -ItemType HardLink -Path "D:\WallPaper\Lightning.jpg" -Target D:\Photos\2009\Dec\Lightning.jpg"
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- [MKLink](https://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html)
- **`mklink /?`**

> ```
> Creates a symbolic link.
>
> MKLINK [[/D] | [/H] | [/J]] Link Target
>
>         /D      Creates a directory symbolic link.  Default is a file
>                 symbolic link.
>         /H      Creates a hard link instead of a symbolic link.
>         /J      Creates a Directory Junction.
>         Link    Specifies the new symbolic link name.
>         Target  Specifies the path (relative or absolute) that the new link
>                 refers to.
> ```

- [New-Item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?view=powershell-7)
- [Hard link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link)
- [Understanding NTFS Hard Links, Junctions and
  Symbolic Links](https://www.2brightsparks.com/resources/articles/NTFS-Hard-Links-Junctions-and-Symbolic-Links.pdf)

  > A hard link is a file that represents another file on the same volume
  > without actually duplicating the data of that file. More than one hard
  > link can be created to point at the same file. ***Hard links cannot link
  > to a file that is on a different partition, volume or drive.*** Hard
  > links on directories are not supported as it would lead to
  > inconsistencies in parent directory entries.

Comment: @RockPaperLz- Mask it or Casket It is possible to do this via PowerShell with some PS commands as well I can post if you wish later but it'll be a few hours before I get to it if so (example: `New-Item -ItemType HardLink -Path "Link" -Target "Target"`). This is an easy way though to accomplish what you ask.

Comment: The software Link Shell Extension provides GUI facilities to easily create links of all sorts, instead of tediously typing out command lines for each file: https://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html

Comment: Thank you!  That is exactly the type of cleverness I was thinking of.  I can't believe I've gone through all these years without using hard links.  Do hard links always have to be on the same partition as the original source?

Comment: @kreemoweet Thank you for the software recommendation! I will definitely check it out.  I'm very good with CLI, but a well-designed GUI often makes things easier, especially if it's not something you need to do every day.

Comment: I appreciate your offer for PowerShell commands.  I'm comfortable in PowerShell as well as DOS batch files, but find batch files a little easier because I've been using them since DOS was created.  Any reason to use PowerShell instead of batch files?  Either way, if you have time, it would be a nice addition to your great answer.

Comment: After completing my reading of all the helpful links you provided, I have now learned that hard links must always be on the same partition, so scratch that little question. ;)

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket There you go sir, added to answer as suggested as well. I'm glad I was able to help you find a solution.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Thank you so much for all your help.  I'm playing around with hard links right now.  Very powerful and handy.

Comment: Follow up question, if you happen to have the time: https://superuser.com/questions/1596840/why-do-files-with-multiple-hard-links-lose-authenticated-users-read-write-acce