# Why do files with multiple hard links lose 'Authenticated Users' read/write access (and how to make not happen)?

Tags: windows, security, file-management, recycle-bin, hardlink

After playing with hard links on a test Win7 system after receiving a fantastic answer by community member **[Pimp Juice IT](https://superuser.com/users/510662/pimp-juice-it)** to another question ([Is there a clever way to group a bunch of files together besides using a folder (for Windows desktop background images)?](https://superuser.com/questions/1596646/is-there-a-clever-way-to-group-a-bunch-of-files-together-besides-using-a-folder)), I noticed that files with multiple hard links lose their `Authenticated Users` read/write access security setting if any of their hard links are placed in the Recycle Bin.  This also causes a padlock to appear over all other hard links to the file.

Actually emptying the Recycle Bin makes no difference.

Bypassing the Recycle Bin and directly deleting a hard link does not cause this to happen.

Why does this happen when deleting a hard link to the Recycle Bin (when multiple hard links point to the same object), and is there any way to prevent it from happening?

Comment: WOW!  What a crazy bug.  If only Microsoft hadn't fired all of its testers.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Microsoft didn't fire them.  They just repurposed "customers" as "testers" and removed 100% of the compensation.  ;)

Comment: Am I crazy here or isn't that exactly how hard links are supposed to function? Are you looking for symbolic links? `mklink link target`?

Comment: @Hashgrammer My current understanding is that creating or removing an additional hard link to an object should not do this.  After all, directly deleting a hard link does not do this, but sending it to the Recycle Bin does (and emptying the Recycle Bin does not result in a state the same as directly deleting a hard link).

Comment: Think about it. A hard link is just that, it's the same as if you modified the file itself. It's a whereas a shortcut would point to another location, a hard link points to the same file sector on the hard drive as the file itself does in the original location. Now think about the actions performed when putting an item into the recycle bin. Permissions are changed because you cannot use the file without first restoring it from the recycle bin. So when you trash that hard link, and the file's permissions are modified, the original file and all the other hard links also point to that file.

Comment: To understand what I just said you need a very firm understanding of the difference between a hard link, and a symbolic link (or even a shortcut). [Here is a quick read on that.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23251) I genuinely think this is performing As-Intended from a strictly technical point of view. (i.e. "permissions must be the same as those on the "original" - permissions are stored in the inode, not the directory entry") If you want what you're describing, you need to use symbolic links.

Comment: @Hashgrammer Thank you for your insight.  I will real the link you provided and also give much thought to what you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick read on the [difference between a Symbolic Link and aa Hard Link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23251).

In the simplest terms (an arrow represents "points to" or a direct pointer):

Shortcut:

[image: Shortcut]

Symbolic Link:

[image: Sym Link]

Hard Link:

[image: Hard link]

---

With the little node representing the NTFS equivalent of an inode on the hard drive in which the file resides.

So when you take that hard link, and toss it into the Recycle Bin, just like any other file, Windows is changing permissions and doing things to the file to keep it in a Recycled State (it can only be used again if it is restored, you cannot use it from the Recycle Bin). So when you do this to a hard link, as you can see above, you're really doing it to the core file (as is expected with a hard link), and thus, causing the changes to be reflected in all the other hard links as well.

**The solution to your issue would be to either utilize Symbolic Links or shortcuts, or use the `del` command from the command line on the hard link you want to remove instead of putting it through the Recycle Bin.**

For more information, simply read the [Microsoft Documentation on Hard Links](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/hard-links-and-junctions):

> Note that the attributes on the file are reflected in every hard link
> to that file, and changes to that file's attributes propagate to all
> the hard links. For example if you reset the READONLY attribute on a
> hard link to delete that particular hard link, and there are multiple
> hard links to the actual file, then you will need to reset the
> READONLY bit on the file from one of the remaining hard links to bring
> the file and all remaining hard links back to the READONLY state.

Comment: So this is just a downside to using hard links that if you do not permanently delete it, the adjustment made to make the hard link available for restore in the recycle bin really modifies the NTFS equivalent Linux inode file content pointer? I think this may be right, whatever the recycle bin is doing to make it restorable is doing that to the file content rather than the pointer and that affects the authenticated users NTFS ACL attributes per the other pointer you are looking at to see the content and attributes.

Comment: "We", as in, you and I, or the person who would leave the comment and I. *chortle* Yes, that is a mostly accurate summary. To the last sentence, "whatever the recycle bin is doing to make it restorable is doing that to the file content rather than the pointer" exactly, because it's operating on a hard link, which is JUST AS MUCH document.txt as the original document.txt you originally created.

Comment: (cont'd) From the link I provided in the top of the answer "[directories mklinks are] indistinguishable from other directory entries, because every directory entry is hard link" and if it's a file "permissions must be the same as those on the "original" (permissions are stored in the inode, not the directory entry)" meaning when recycle bin modifies the hard link in a way that affects Auth Users permissions, it's modifying that NTFS equivalent of an inode and therefor all other links to that file, including the original, are also affected. Correct.

Comment: Additionally, [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/hard-links-and-junctions), which I am going to work into my answer.

Comment: @RockPaperLz I updated this answer to give a satisfactory alternative, whereby you can continue to use hard links. The solution is in bold. Everything else is an explanation of "Why".

Comment: Typically I remove it from my answer after constructive criticism has been made and the answer is fleshed out to satisfaction. It would be too late for me to edit my first comment, but, as planned, I'll remove it from the answer.